# Trouble debugging binarysearch function in C

Tags: c, file, fseek

i'm trying to make a binary search that searches through an ordered file of numbers. Although, even though it worked in "main" before I converted this into a function, it has managed to have some weird behavior after my fseek().

Any suggestions?

```
int BinarySearch(FILE *cp, char *CPR, int *position) {

  int i, lines, current_line;
  double CPR_number, CPR_check;
  char CPR_check_string[CPR_LEN];

  sscanf(CPR, "%lf", &CPR_number);

  fseek(cp, 0L, SEEK_END);
  lines = ftell(cp)/12;

  current_line = ftell(cp)/2 - ((ftell(cp)/2) % 12);

  for (i = 0; i < log10(lines)/log10(2); i++) {

    fseek(cp, current_line, SEEK_SET);

    /* Read CPR as string */
    fscanf(cp, "%[0-9]", CPR_check_string);

    /* Convert to number */
    sscanf(CPR_check_string, "%lf", &CPR_check);

    if (CPR_number == CPR_check) {
      printf("This happens\n");
      *position = ftell(cp);
      return TRUE;
    } else if (CPR_number < CPR_check) {
      current_line = ftell(cp)/2 - ((ftell(cp)/2) % 12);
    } else if (CPR_number > CPR_check) {
      current_line = ftell(cp) + ftell(cp)/2 - ((ftell(cp) + ftell(cp)/2) % 12);
    }
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

It doesn't seem to run the rest of the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "weird behavior"? What happens? For some specific input, what is the expected and actual output? How do you call this function? What is the contents of the file? Is the file opened in binary or text mode? When you divide positions by 12, are you counting the newlines correctly? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well i tried printf("test\n"); before the first fseek and it worked, but after it, it doesn't print anything. I call the function like: "if(BinarySearch(cp, CPR, &position)). The file holds 9 lines of numbers of 10 digits + newline, which is 12 bytes pr. line. 

Does this clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer, it was my FILE pointer that was off, it had to be a pointer to a pointer so FILE **.

Comment: That is clearly not the actual solution - `fseek` etc... take a `FILE *` and your compiler should be complaining a lot if you pass it a `FILE **`. There is likely some undefined behaviour else where in your code that this solution is fixing by pure chance.